# Nested pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, matching

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to understand how pattern matching works. So I wrote this basic code, which returned the expected result:

```
def test(choice: Int): String = choice match {
  case x if x > 0 && x%2 == 0 => "positive even number"
  case x if x > 0 && x%2 != 0 => "positive odd number"
  case 0 => "null"
  case x if x < 0 && x%2 == 0 => "negative even number" 
  case x if x < 0 && x%2 != 0 => "negative odd number"
}
```

Now I'm trying to do something a little more elaborate:

```
def test(choice: Int): String = choice match {

  case x if x%2 == 0 => x match {
    case y if y > 0 => "even and positive number" 
    case y if y < 0 => "even and negative number"
    }
  case 0 => "null"
  case x if x%2 != 0 => x match {
    case y if y > 0 => "odd and positive number" 
    case y if y < 0 => "odd and negative number"
    }
}
```

But it failed. Here's the error message on the console:

```
scala> def test(choice: Int): String = choice match {
     |
     |   case x if x%2 == 0 => x match {
     | case y if y > 0 => "even and positive number"
     | Display all 600 possibilities? (y or n)
     [...]

     |  if y < 0 => "even and negative number"
<console>:5: error: '(' expected but identifier found.
 if y < 0 => "even and negative number"
    ^

    [...]
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong and give me some details about what I misunderstand about Scala in general and the `match` method in particular.

Comment: ```
| Display all 600 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Definitely means you have a tab somewhere. Have you tried to use the paste mode (scala> :paste)?

Comment: Pattern matching can be very useful and powerful. For this computation, however, I wouldn't use it. It just complicates the underlying logic.

Comment: pattern matching with only guards and no pattern seems a bad use generally

Comment: thank you for your help. Indeed the problem was in the tab. it compiles now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles for me. The order of cases doesn't matter for the success of compilation (however, the `case 0` branch will never match, because `case x if x%2==0` matches `x=0`. You may want to make the `case 0` branch the first one)

I believe your problem is because of using tabs instead of spaces in the terminal.

If you use this code in a file in a project, it'll compile just as well. If you want it to work in the console, you can either:

- convert the tabs to spaces before pasting the code
- enter paste mode in the REPL using the `:paste` command, paste the code and exit paste mode with `Ctrl-D` (or whatever the REPL tells you the combination is - that's the one on Mac).

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, you test for x>0 in the first 2 cases, then for 0 itself.

In the second code, you don't test for x>0, but x%2 == 0 which already matches for x = 0, and a second, outer match isn't considered.

If you put the explicit 0 match on top, it might work, but I didn't look for a second error and only matched for the first error I could find. :)

Comment: Yep, i didn't focus on that. I just wanted to made it compile. The problem was in the tab. it works now. thank you